# Determine functions in R in uninstalled packages?

Tags: r, package

I know there are several ways to determine the functions in a given package in R, provided the package is already installed.  For instance, one can use any of the following to find the functions associated with the XML package:

```
lsf.str("package:XML")

help(package="XML")

ls(pos = "package:XML")
```

But I want to find all the functions for a package, listed in a format similar to the way one of these 3 methods presents them in R, without actually installing the package.  I know the pdf manual for a given package contains the list of functions; but I need something more dynamic (either that can be accessed in R or on a webpage, for instance).  And I am not finding anything like this on the CRAN website either.  Here is the XML site, for instance:  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html

And ideally I need this to generalize to any/all (or at least most) of the 5,000+ existing R packages.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you could try to query this site: http://www.rdocumentation.org , or to see with its author how to get the actual index.

Comment: Wow! That is great--thanks Karl.  I did not know of this website but this is exactly what I was looking for.